# isc-dhcp-server configuration

Tags: debian, isc-dhcpd

so I've been bashing the keyboard for hours now and finally I surrender. Anyone else have an Idea of how to configure the ISC-DHCP-SERVER on Debian 9?

So it should be pretty simple I guess. I've followed this tutorial:
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-and-configure-isc-dhcp-server-in-debian-9/
and I've used their recomended tutorial configuration file. But no matter what i try i always end up with the Error: "expecting a semicolon on line 14". As far as I can see i obviously have one there.

Can It be that the settings I use must actually be valid. Eg i can't just take a random domain name such as "example.com"?

Or could It be that the network card has wrong configurations?

dhcpd.conf:

```
ddns-update-style none;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
#ping true;
option domain-name-servers 172.27.15.2, 10.72.81.2;
option domain-name "example.com";
authorative;
log-facility local7;

subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.1.50 192.168.1.115;
option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.254, 10.128.254.254;
option domain-name “example.com”;
option routers 192.168.1.1;
option netbios-name-servers 192.168.1.3;
option netbios-node-type 8;
get-lease-hostnames true;
use-host-decl-names true;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
}
```

network/interfaces conf:

```
iface ens33 inet static
    address 192.168.1.7
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.254
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Any input i appreciated

Comment: i think there are no "; e.g. domain-name example.com;

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: There *are* quote marks in the example configuration of isc-dhcpd, and I've used them for other options in my working config. However, if the `dhcp.conf` is verbatim, OP is using the wrong quote character `“` instead of `"`.

Comment: Try removing lines around line 14 and see what changes in the error message.

Comment: @dirkt wow. now I feel stupid, probably justifeid. Submit that as an answer and I'll mark it as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character used for the quotation mark is wrong: One needs to use `"` (ASCII) instead of `“` (Unicode LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK).

The somewhat confusing "expecting a semicolon message" is there because the parser doesn't see anything that makes sense for him when encountering the unicode quotation mark, so he expects the line to be concluded with a semicolon.

BTW, using a font that makes a clear difference between those two quotation marks (and all the other variants of single or double quotation marks) helps a lot.